# Como posso ativar meu iTunnes Connect?

Tags: ios, swift

Possuo duas contas uma de Agente (Total Acesso) e outra de Administrador para Desenvolvimento.
Quando eu tento me connectar no iTunnes Connect com usuário agente  não aparece a opção My Apps.

**Desta forma:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Aparece assim :**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como posso resolver este problema ?

Comment: Em inglês, não da LOL

Comment: De boa :) era só pra avisar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Possível problema no acesso da conta:

Caso você tenha concluído todo processo de registrar uma conta e mesmo assim continua sem acesso às opções de team agent, entre em contanto com a Apple e explique seu problema através deste link: https://developer.apple.com/contact/submit.php

Comment: Minha conta é paga!

Comment: Sim @Highlander você tem uma conta que é o _team agent_ da Apple, usando essa conta você precisa acessar o iTunes Connect e adicionar o outro usuário e colocar ele como `Admin`.

Comment: Colocar ele como admin no iTunnes Connect ?como ? não seria em Member Center ?

Comment: @Highlander editei minha resposta adicionando os detalhes necessários para se fazer isso ;)

Comment: Pois eh, mas o meu team agent não aparece essa opção no itunnes connect, perguntei no soen e me disseram para entrar em contato com a apple: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34301525/how-can-i-activate-my-itunes-connect